# What does "r/m8" mean when used in instruction encoding tables?

Tags: assembly, x86

The `ADD` instruction documentation from [this page](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_5.html) has the following table with various encodings:

[image]

I believe that `imm8` means an immediate value whose size is 8 bits (for example: `BYTE 123`).

And I believe that `r32` means a register whose size is 32 bits (for example: `EAX`)

But what does `r/m8` mean? Does it mean that I can use a register whose size is 8 bits (for example: `AL]`) or a memory location whose size is 8 bits (for example: `BYTE [myvar]`)?

Comment: Please just ask the question you want to ask...

Comment: @old_timer This question has absolutely nothing to do with any other question I asked, I just want to know what the abbreviations means.

Comment: same as r/m16 and r/m32. directly out of the intel manual r8 encoding 000 is AL, r8 encoding 001 is CL, encoding 010 is DL, and so on down the table.  for r16 000 is AX, and so on down the table.   They walk you through all of the addressing modes and such before they actually dive into the instruction set.  but you already knew this from your prior two questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That web page is a html conversion of the official intel documentation. You should read that instead, especially since it has a section *3.1.1.3 Instruction Column in the Opcode Summary Table* which says:

> r/m8 -- A byte operand that is either the contents of a byte
>   general-purpose register (AL, CL, DL, BL, AH, CH, DH, BH, BPL, SPL,
>   DIL and SIL) or a byte from memory. Byte registers R8L - R15L are
>   available using REX.R in 64-bit mode.

So yes, it means what you said.

Comment: Of all the abbreviations you see in the Intel manuals, this is one of the more intuitive ones. "r" for register, "m" for memory, and a number for the operand size. Way more clear than, say, ["mod-reg-r/m byte"](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0270_modrm_byte.htm).